# Form Update - Not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

All,

I'm migrating from the obsolete `mysql_query` to `mysqli`and during the process I'm having some issues with the form updating changes. Specifically, it seems as if the `$ud_id` variable to get the `id` is not working.

The queries are written to left outer join link tables `empinfo` and `headcount` in which both of these of the linking primary id.

Here is the **edit.php** page which works and loads as intended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<div class="header">
<?php include 'header.php';?>
</div>

<center>

<?php
    // db connection
    include_once('../connection.php');

        // id pull from url
        $ID = (int)$_GET['id'];
            // get results from database
            $query = "SELECT headcount.*, empinfo.*
            FROM headcount
            LEFT OUTER JOIN empinfo
            ON headcount.id = empinfo.id
            WHERE headcount.id = '$ID'";

            $response = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))

            {

                echo "<form action='update.php' method='post'>";
                echo '<div style="width:40%;padding:0 10pt 0 0;float:middle;">';
                if ($row['isActive'] === '1')
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ud_isActive" value="1" checked>Active<br />';
                else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ud_isActive" value="0">Active<br />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="ud_ID" value="<?=$ID;?>">';
                echo "ID #: <input type='text' name='ud_hwid' value=". $row['id'] ." disabled readonly><br />";
                echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="ud_EmployeeName" value="'. $row["EmployeeName"] .'"><br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<a href="mailto:' . $row["Email"] .'">Email</a>: <input type="text" name="ud_Email" value="'. $row["Email"] .'"><br>';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'DOB: <input type="text" name="ud_DOB" value='. $row["DOB"] .'><br />';
                echo 'Age: <input type="text" name="ud_Age" value='. $row["Age"] .'><br />';
                if ($row['isUnderage'] === '1')
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="isUnderage" value="1" checked>Underage<br />';
                else
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="isUnderage" value="0">Underage<br />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div style="width:40%;padding:0 10pt 0 0;float:middle;">';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Address: <input type="text" name="ud_StreetAddress" value="'. $row["StreetAddress"] .'"><br />';
                echo 'City: <input type="text" name="ud_City" value="'. $row["City"] .'"><br />';
                echo 'Zip Code: <input type="text" name="ud_ZipCode" value="'. $row["ZipCode"] .'"><br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Home Phone: <input type="text" name="ud_HomePhone" value="'. $row["HomePhone"] .'"><br />';
                echo 'Wireless: <input type="text" name="ud_Wireless" value="'. $row["Wireless"] .'"><br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Home Department: <input type="text" name="ud_HomeDept" value="'. $row["HomeDept"] .'"><br />';
                echo 'Department Manager: <input type="text" name="ud_Manager" value="'. $row["Manager"] .'"><br />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Live Orientation:<input type="date" name="LODate" value=""><br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'Online Training: <input type="date" name="OTTraining" value=""><br />';



          }

    ?>
    <br />

    <input type="Submit">
    </form> <br />
      <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>
    <br />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the **update.php** -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<style type="text/css">
#wrap {
   width:600px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:300px;
}
#right_col {
   float:right;
   width:300px;
}
</style>

<div class="header">
<?php include 'header.php';?>
</div>

<center>

<?php
$ud_ID = $_REQUEST["ID"];
$ud_EmployeeName = $_POST["ud_EmployeeName"];
$ud_Email = $_POST["ud_Email"];
$ud_DOB = $_POST["ud_DOB"];
$ud_Age = $_POST["ud_Age"];
$ud_StreetAddress = $_POST["ud_StreetAddress"];
$ud_City = $_POST["ud_City"];
$ud_ZipCode = $_POST["ud_ZipCode"];
$ud_HomePhone = $_POST["ud_HomePhone"];
$ud_Wireless = $_POST["ud_Wireless"];
$ud_HomeDept = $_POST["ud_HomeDept"];
$ud_Manager = $_POST["ud_Manager"];

// db connection
include_once('../connection.php');

$query = "UPDATE headcount SET
EmployeeName = '$ud_EmployeeName', Email = '$ud_Email',
DOB = '$ud_DOB', Age = '$ud_Age', StreetAddress = '$ud_StreetAddress',
City = '$ud_City', ZipCode = '$ud_ZipCode', HomePhone = '$ud_HomePhone',
Wireless = '$ud_Wireless', HomeDept = '$ud_HomeDept', Manager = '$ud_Manager'
WHERE ID = '$ud_ID'";

    $response = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  echo $ud_ID;
  echo $ud_EmployeeName;

if ($response)
  echo '<p>Record Updated<p> <br /> <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>';
else
  echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

At the line 52 of **update.php**  you will notice I use echo `$ud_ID` and `$ud_EmployeeName` - This is to show me what the variable is displaying. The `$ud_EmployeeName` appears and the `$ud_ID` does not.

I also have tried using

```
$ud_ID = $_POST["ID"];
```

and I no results.

Additionally, on **edit.php** I have tried:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ud_ID" value='. $row["id"] .'><br />';
```

and I receive the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ID in update.php on line 27
```

When I click the `submit` button, I receive the message that the record has been updated but on refresh, the record has the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi use name property to get value

```
$ud_ID = $_POST['ud_ID'];
```

Comment: Thank you, Mamta. Worked perfectly.